# failed to mount cifs via autofs

Tags: linux, automount, cifs, autofs

I try to tune mounting and give next error in /var/log/messages:

```
Nov 10 10:37:00 cvv automount[3038]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/cifs/acad
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> Usage: mount -V                 : print version
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount -h                 : print this help
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount                    : list mounted filesystems
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount -l                 : idem, including volume labels
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> So far the informational part. Next the mounting.
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> The command is `mount [-t fstype] something somewhere'.
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> Details found in /etc/fstab may be omitted.
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount -a [-t|-O] ...     : mount all stuff from /etc/fstab
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount device             : mount device at the known place
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount directory          : mount known device here
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount -t type dev dir    : ordinary mount command
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> Note that one does not really mount a device, one mounts
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> a filesystem (of the given type) found on the device.
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> One can also mount an already visible directory tree elsewhere:
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount --bind olddir newdir
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> or move a subtree:
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount --move olddir newdir
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> One can change the type of mount containing the directory dir:
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount --make-shared dir
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount --make-slave dir
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount --make-private dir
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount --make-unbindable dir
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> One can change the type of all the mounts in a mount subtree
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> containing the directory dir:
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount --make-rshared dir
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount --make-rslave dir
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount --make-rprivate dir
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >>        mount --make-runbindable dir
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> A device can be given by name, say /dev/hda1 or /dev/cdrom,
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> or by label, using  -L label  or by uuid, using  -U uuid .
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> Other options: [-nfFrsvw] [-o options] [-p passwdfd].
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: >> For many more details, say  man 8 mount .
Nov 10 10:37:01 cvv automount[3333]: mount(generic): failed to mount (null) (type cifs) on /mnt/cifs/acad
```

what additional info required?

Comment: How are you trying to mount? Manually or do you have a entry in /etc/fstab? Give the command or the content of your /etc/fstab file.

Comment: VIA AUTOFS. There are no problem in mounting manual or via fstab.